# Windows registry comparison tool, hierachical/collapsible

Tags: gratis, windows-registry

I need to compare two Windows registry `.reg` files (taken before and after a problem appeared).

- I tried WinMerge, but it does not display any highlighting even so the files are different.
- I copied the files to Linux and tried Meld but it says `before.reg appears to be a binary file`.
- Regshot can only compare the registry at the present time, it does not have any dialog to enter an existing registry file.
- RegDiff Registry Differences Picker just dumps differences to a text file, no highlighting.

Requirements:

- Highlight differences
- Ideally shows keys as a hierarchy, so that I can press a `[-]` button to collapse the whole comparizon of `HKEY_USERS` for instance. A bit like some diff viewers can show differences between two hierarchies of folders.
- Works file `.reg` files of 300 MB
- Free
- Any OS is OK, webapp OK too

Comment: Did you press the refresh button (F5) and activate a highlighting method in the View menu in Winmerge? Hard to believe it does not display differences.

Comment: Such a tool should consider the structure of the registry, i.e. ignore the order of items in each branch.

Comment: Nicolas, did you happen to find anything? I'm now facing the same problem, except with two different mounted hives in a live registry. If there isn't an existing one I might end up writing my own...

Comment: @Thomas: Hard to believe but I really tried for a while, including refreshing. If order is not semantically important, then ignoring it would be good, yes.

Comment: @Bob: Not found yet, please star the question and add an answer after you write your tool :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Sorry... I decided I'd be better off spending a few hours manually comparing and restoring from backup rather than trying to mess with designing a good diff UI (especially if one wants to see ACLs too). Though... that brings up an interesting idea... if I could dump keys to folders and values to files, I could then run a standard directory diff tool over it...

Comment: @Bob: https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-dotnet/tree/master/sample/RegistryFS shows the registry as a mounted drive, I used it last year, it can be useful if going the way you suggest.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Oh, look, put that together and we have a workable (if not particularly elegant) solution. Nice! Though I'm currently hoping I'll never actually need it ;) In your case I suppose you'd import the `.reg` and mount it as a separate hive first - possibly with a find/replace to fix up the paths pre-import.

Comment: @Bob: There is a problem though: That tool does not read from .reg files, only from the computer's live registry.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, my answer is not free, but it does most of what you want and it has a free trial, so I'm going to write it up as an answer.

BeyondCompare (Professional version) will do most of what you want. It works for Windows/Linux and Mac.
It is not free, but the trial version will allow you to test the below functionality for 30days.

**Beyond compare allows you**

- to compare different registry snapshots (reg files).
- to highlight differences between registry snapshots.
- It shows a hierarchy so that you can collapse folders that you
  don't want to see.

[image: BeyondCompare Windows Registry Comparison and collapsable hierarchy]

- Not requested, but very userful- it allows you to skip to the next
  difference.
- I'm not sure of the max file size that can be compared.

I'm not affiliated with the company. I've only recently started using the software.